# integrate Bootstrap's progress bar in reactjs - invoking java servlet API call from superagent

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, progress-bar, superagent

I have a requirement that, i have to generate a Excel report and have to download the same from the react js application. I do want to integrate Bootstrap's progress bar while doing this process.

How i can integrate progress bar here.?

Please find my code below.

BootStrap Progress bar code:

```
<div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-
      valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
      </div>
</div>
```

ReactJS (SuperAgent) code for generating Excel sheet and download the same.

```
handleInvoice(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault()
    var item = this.state.item;
    var lines = item.order;
    var request = require('superagent');
    var apiBaseUrl = "api/Invoice";
    var req = request.get(apiBaseUrl);
    req.query({ item : item.id})
    req.end(function(err,res){
         if(err){
             alert(" error"+err);
             confirmAlert({
                    message: 'Invoice is not prepared properly.....', 
                    confirmLabel: 'Ok', 
                });
          }
         else{
                window.location= 'api/Invoice?item=' + item.id,'';
                element.click();
            } 

        });
}
```

ReactJS Botton code to invoke handleInvoice() method :

```
return ( <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={ 
         this.handleInvoice } > Invoice </button> );
```

Please find my servlet code :

```
try {
        String reportname = "Invoice";  
        resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
        reportname + ".xls");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook1=service.getCommercialInvoiceService(id);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook1.write(outByteStream);
            byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
            int fileSize=outArray.length;
            outStream = resp.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(outArray);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            resp.setHeader("Content-Length", ""+fileSize);
            System.out.println("File Size"+fileSize);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new ServletException(ioe);
        }
```

Please find my servlet code., where am getting the size of the file and am setting it to the response header also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

superagent package has a [progress tracking](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#progress-tracking) feature.

> SuperAgent fires `progress` events on upload and download of large
>   files.

You can use this feature to get current get requests percentage and apply that percentage to the progress bar.

**Example**

```
handleInvoice(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var item = this.state.item;
  var lines = item.order;
  var request = require('superagent');
  var apiBaseUrl = "api/Invoice";
  var req = request.get(apiBaseUrl);
  req.query({
    item: item.id
  });

  req.on('progress', event => {
    // set state for the current progress percentage
    this.setState({ progress: event.percent });
  });

  req.end(function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      alert(" error" + err);
      confirmAlert({
        message: 'Invoice is not prepared properly.....',
        confirmLabel: 'Ok',
      });
    }
    else {
      window.location = 'api/Invoice?item=' + item.id, '';
      element.click();
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={this.state.progress} aria-
      valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: event.percent is coming undefined. -- Not sure why its coming as undefined.

Comment: In documentation it says _may be missing if file size is unknown_ for the percentage. This might be because the server is not giving enough information about the file. you might need to add some headers to your api response to let know superagent the size of the request.

Comment: Please find my servlet code where am getting the file size and also am setting in the header also in content-length.

Comment: Please add the information about your server code to the question not to the answer.

Comment: is you api with Java?

Comment: I don't know anything about Java. Update your question and add Java related tag so maybe someone can answer better.

Comment: event.percent is not coming as response from superagent. I tried by printing the event.  alert(JSON.stringify(event));  Response : {"isTrusted":true,"direction":"download"}

Comment: Like I said before, documentation says it may be missing because of file size is unknown.

Comment: Am getting that event.percent now. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that you sort it out. Can you please add it yo your question as an update and show how you sort it out. It may be useful for others later on.

Comment: I just got that event.percent. am getting some issue while integrate with Bootstrap's progress bar. That component is not rendering properly.. I thought off to post that issue too...